# php check if variable length equals a value

Tags: php

Need to check if **$message** length is 7 characters or less, if so, do action A, if not, do action B. Is this correct syntax? I think im doing something wrong?

```
<?php

if (strlen($message) <= 7) {
    echo $actiona;
} else {
    echo $actionb;
}

?>
```

Comment: Does a php block need to start with '<?php'?

Comment: Why do you think you're doing something wrong ? Doesn't it work ?

Comment: @seth '<?' is fine, if the php config allows it.

Comment: I pasted the working code from the offline file i thought i uploaded before i fixed a semi colon issue. Thanks guys for the help though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's fine. For example, let's run the following:

```
<?php

$message = "Hello there!";

if (strlen($message) <= 7){
    echo "It is less than or equal to 7 characters.";
} 
else 
{
    echo "It is greater than 7 characters.";
}
?>
```

It will print: "It is greater than 7 characters."

Comment: This is the best code for doing this out of all the ones I've seen recommended on stackoverflow. Source: tested them

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to use the PHP shorthand if/else using the ternary operators (?:).

For example, instead of:

```php
<?php

if (strlen($message) <= 7) {
    echo $actiona;
} else {
    echo $actionb;
}

?>
```

You can write it as:

```php
<?php echo strlen($message) <= 7 ? $actiona : $actionb; ?>
```

See [How do I use shorthand if / else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-do-i-use-shorthand-if-else) for information on the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

What error messages are you receiving?

I would check that when you set `$message` before hand, you haven't misspelt it or used incorrect capitalization (keeping in mind that php is cAsE sensitive).

Answer (score 1):

That's OK.

But you should use long php tags (short tags can be disabled ; and quite often are) :

```
<?php
// ... PHP code
?>
```

(closing tag being optional, if your file contains only PHP)