# How to replace "if" statement with a ternary operator ( ? : )?

Tags: php, conditional-operator

Based on the examples [from this page](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-shorthand-if-else-examples), I wanted to convert the below `if` statement to a ternary operator.

Working code using `if` statement:

```
if (!empty($address['street2'])) echo $address['street2'].'<br />';
```

I am not sure how this should be written using a ternary operator so that the `echo` works only if `street2` exists in the array and is not an empty string.

Comment: Your question is fooling some volunteers and researchers because you are not writing an assignment using a shorthand ternary expression (there is no "Elvis Operator") -- you are writing a longhand ternary expression.  The difference is that you are declaring both of the returned  values depending on the evaluation.  In a shorthand evaluation, if the input value is "truthy", it is returned; if it is "falsey" then the fallback value is returned (this is the value declared after the Elvis Operator).  There is also a noticeably poor implementation of the Null Coalescing Operator here too.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

The

```
(condition) ? /* value to return if condition is true */ 
            : /* value to return if condition is false */ ;
```

syntax is not a "shorthand if" operator (the `?` is called the conditional operator) because you cannot execute code in the same manner as if you did:

```
if (condition) {
    /* condition is true, do something like echo */
}
else {
    /* condition is false, do something else */
}
```

In your example, you are executing the `echo` statement when the `$address` is not empty. You can't do this the same way with the conditional operator. What you can do however, is `echo` the result of the conditional operator:

```
echo empty($address['street2']) ? "Street2 is empty!" : $address['street2'];
```

and this will display "Street is empty!" if it is empty, otherwise it will display the street2 address.

Comment: It's the difference between statement and expression

Comment: whats the shorthand again? `condition ?: false` which evaluates to `condition` if its true?

Comment: how about if 3 condition?  it still work?

Answer (score 55):

### PHP 7+

As of PHP 7, this task can be performed simply by using the [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) like this :

```
echo $address['street2'] ?? 'Empty';
```

Comment: Just FYI, if `$address['street2']` is an empty string. It will accept it and won't return `'Empty'`. `isset() != empty()`. This will only work if the value is `null`

Comment: Well, I was just providing an example. But I have modified the code. Thanks !

Comment: What is the output if `$address['street2']` is not empty?

Comment: If $address['street2'] is not empty, it will output some form of “true”. The usual form of the above is more like: `echo $address['street2'] ?? 'Empty';` however as mentioned, it is the “**null** coalescing operator” so it only tests for null and not empty. This is because ?? Is effectively a shorthand for isset().

Comment: Signed in just to downvote this answer. This doesn't do at all what's advertised.

Comment: **THIS ANSWER IS WRONG!** Proof: https://ideone.com/bLJM55 It echoes out the result of `!empty($address['street2'])` which is true, and PHP's `echo` will print this as `1`. Yeah, bizarre, but that's how it is.

Comment: `empty()` **NEVER** returns `null`, so `??` will never give the desired result.  I absolutely **HATE** when incorrect answers poison the Stack Overflow knowledge pool and give provably incorrect advice to researchers!

Comment: I rolled back the edit since it made the answer absolutely wrong. It still isn't completely true, but at least it shows a working example now. `!empty` would never return `null` so null-coalescing operator can't be used together with it.

Comment: Dear researchers, this answer is still incorrect for the posted question.  The null coalescing operator will catch a `null` value but not an empty string.  Researchers should not use this answer and they should certainly not upvote it.  It is bad advice.

Comment: Yeah it's incorrect, can we remove it.

Answer (score 33):

**Basic True / False Declaration**

```
$is_admin = ($user['permissions'] == 'admin' ? true : false);
```

**Conditional Welcome Message**

```
echo 'Welcome '.($user['is_logged_in'] ? $user['first_name'] : 'Guest').'!';
```

**Conditional Items Message**

```
echo 'Your cart contains '.$num_items.' item'.($num_items != 1 ? 's' : '').'.';
```

ref: https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples

Comment: you got it from the short hand website and didn't even reference it

Comment: @Richard added references

Comment: Is it ? In the context of StackOverflow it's always a thin line, I mean the Q asked for something, unable to find it by him/herself, and then somebody else delivered this content. Is it unfair to copy existing content if it helps and adds value to this Q/A ? I think answers on StackOverflow are not "your own content" ... hmmm

Comment: First example is incorrect. The `)` is misplaced. It should precede the `?`. The complete statement should be `$is_admin = ($user['permissions'] == 'admin') ? true : false;`

Comment: Also, completely useless without an eplanation of what the examples do.

Answer (score 28):

It's the Ternary operator a.k.a Elvis operator (google it :P) you are looking for.

```
echo $address['street2'] ?: 'Empty';
```

It returns the value of the variable or default if the variable is empty.

Comment: @Structed I can't disagree with what you say but, googling for this will give you the propper result and it's an easier term to remind

Comment: Correct answer! The other upvoted answer from 2017 is not working!

Answer (score 15):

The ternary operator is just a shorthand for and if/else block. Your working code does not have an else condition, so is not suitable for this.

The following example will work:

```
echo empty($address['street2']) ? 'empty' : 'not empty';
```

Answer (score 13):

Quick and short way:

```
echo $address['street2'] ? : "No";
```

Here are some interesting examples, with one or more varied conditions.

```
$color = "blue";

// Example #1 Show color without specifying variable 
echo $color ? : "Undefined";
echo "<br>";

// Example #2
echo $color ? $color : "Undefined";
echo "<br>";

// Example #3
echo ($color) ? $color : "Undefined";
echo "<br>";

// Example #4
echo ($color == "blue") ? $color : "Undefined";
echo "<br>";

// Example #5
echo ($color == "" ? $color : ($color == "blue" ? $color : "Undefined"));
echo "<br>";

// Example #6
echo ($color == "blue" ? $color : ($color == "" ? $color : ($color == "" ? $color : "Undefined")));
echo "<br>";

// Example #7
echo ($color != "") ? ($color != "" ? ($color == "blue" ? $color : "Undefined") : "Undefined") : "Undefined";
echo "<br>";
```

**Update in PHP 7+**

```
// Check if the value exists
echo $_GET['user'] ?? "Undefined"; 
// Before isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'undefined';

// Multiple conditions can be added
echo $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? $color ?? 'Undefined';
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that **when using nested conditional operators, you may want to use parenthesis** to avoid possible issues!

It looks like PHP doesn't work the same way as at least Javascript or C#.

```
$score = 15;
$age = 5;

// The following will return "Exceptional"
echo 'Your score is: ' . ($score > 10 ? ($age > 10 ? 'Average' : 'Exceptional') : ($age > 10 ? 'Horrible' : 'Average'));

// The following will return "Horrible"
echo 'Your score is: ' . ($score > 10 ? $age > 10 ? 'Average' : 'Exceptional' : $age > 10 ? 'Horrible' : 'Average');
```

The same code in Javascript and C# return "Exceptional" in both cases.

In the 2nd case, what PHP does is (or at least that's what I understand):

1. is `$score > 10`? yes
2. is `$age > 10`? no, so the current `$age > 10 ? 'Average' : 'Exceptional'` returns 'Exceptional'
3. then, instead of just stopping the whole statement and returning 'Exceptional', it continues evaluating the next statement
4. the next statement becomes `'Exceptional' ? 'Horrible' : 'Average'` which returns 'Horrible', as 'Exceptional' is truthy

From the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's
>   behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single
>   statement is non-obvious.

Answer (score 2):

**Conditional Welcome Message**

```
echo 'Welcome '.($user['is_logged_in'] ? $user['first_name'] : 'Guest').'!';
```

**Nested PHP Shorthand**

```
echo 'Your score is:  '.($score > 10 ? ($age > 10 ? 'Average' : 'Exceptional') : ($age > 10 ? 'Horrible' : 'Average') );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this even shorter by replacing `echo` with `<?= code ?>`

`<?=(empty($storeData['street2'])) ? 'Yes <br />' : 'No <br />'?>`

This is useful especially when you want to determine, inside a navbar, whether the menu option should be displayed as already visited (clicked) or not:

`<li<?=($basename=='index.php' ? ' class="active"' : '')?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>`

Comment: Are ()'s needed in that <?=?> method?

Answer (score 2):

if else php shorthand ?

Try this

```
  ($value == 1) ? "selected" : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the brackets the wrong way. Try this:

```
$test = (empty($address['street2']) ? 'Yes <br />' : 'No <br />');
```

I think it should work, you can also use:

```
echo (empty($address['street2']) ? 'Yes <br />' : 'No <br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a shorthand ternary operator and it looks like this:

(expression1) ?: expression2 will return *expression1* if it evaluates to true or *expression2* otherwise.

Example:

```
$a = 'Apples';
echo ($a ?: 'Oranges') . ' are great!';
```

will return

```
Apples are great!
```

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the
> ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1
> evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

From the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably should not use ternary operator in php.
Consider next example:

```
<?php

function f1($n) {
    var_dump("first funct");
    return $n == 1;
}

function f2($n) {
    var_dump("second funct");
    return $n == 2;
}


$foo = 1;
$a = (f1($foo)) ? "uno" : (f2($foo)) ? "dos" : "tres";
print($a);
```

How do you think, what `$a` variable will contain? (hint: dos)
And it will remain the same even if `$foo` variable will be assigned to 2.

To make things better you should either refuse to using this operator or surround right part with braces in the following way:

```
$a = (f1($foo)) ? "uno" : ((f2($foo)) ? "dos" : "tres");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary Operator is basically shorthand for if/else statement. We can use to reduce few lines of code and increases readability.

Your code looks cleaner to me. But we can add more cleaner way as follows-

`$test = (empty($address['street2'])) ? 'Yes <br />' : 'No <br />';`

Another way-

`$test = ((empty($address['street2'])) ? 'Yes <br />' : 'No <br />');`

Note-
I have added bracket to whole expression to make it cleaner. I used to do this usually to increase readability.
With PHP7 we can use [Null Coalescing Operator / php 7 ?? operator](https://programmingdive.com/shorthand-comparisons-in-php/) for better approach. But your requirement it does not fit.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think i found the answer in all the above solutions.
Some are also wrong. 
To tests if a variable (or an element of an array, or a property of an object) exists (and is not null) use:
`echo isset($address['street2']) ? $address['street2'] : 'Empty';`

To tests if a variable (...) contains some non-empty data use: 
`echo !empty($address['street2']) ? $address['street2'] : 'Empty';`

Answer (score -1):

If first variable(`$a`) is `null`, then assign value of second variable(`$b`) to first variable(`$a`)

```
 $a = 5;
 $b = 10;   

 $a != ''?$a: $a = $b;

 echo $a;
```