# When clicking input button, php array is empty again

Tags: php

I'm making a To do app for school with PHP. 
The problem i'm facing: 
I have 3 documents: index.php, application.php and CSS

My problem:
every time I add a new task, my array is empty again and will only show the latest added item.

I think the problem is that "application.php" loads again every time I add a task. But I'm not sure how to fix that.

Index.php:

```
<form action="/Periodeopdracht/index.php" method="POST">
<div class="headerToDo">
    <input class="addText title" type="text" value="Click to add a to do" name="nextToDo">
    <input class="clickablePlus" type="submit" value="+" name="submit">
</div>
</form>

<?php if(!$empty): ?>
    <?php foreach ($newToDo as $toDo): ?>
    <div class="toDo">
        <div class="textToDo"><?= $toDo ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Application.php:

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['empty'] = true;
$GLOBALS['newToDo'] = array();

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $empty = false;
    array_unshift($newToDo, $_POST["nextToDo"]);
}

var_dump($newToDo);

?>
```

Comment: Where are you storing `newToDo`, where it is persisted between each execution?

Comment: Create a session using 'session_start'. Put your values in `$_SESSION[ <varname>]`

Comment: You'll likely want to store it in the session using `$_SESSION['newToDo']`

Comment: NOOOOO. use a database.

Comment: As @KarolyHorvath said, you might want to use a database to store the list, however, how complex do you need it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't saving the current todo list anywhere

What your app could do this (in very simple terms, if you wanted to store the list in the session)

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['todoList'] = isset($_SESSION['todoList']) ? $_SESSION['todoList'] : array();

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $empty = false;
    array_unshift($_SESSION['todoList'], $_POST["nextToDo"]);
}
```

Comment: please **don't** use sessions... when the session is gone, you'll lose all the data. you really should store this stuff in a database.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath hence why the **if you wanted to store the list in the session**. Depending on the needs of this system, it shouldn't be overengineered.

Comment: For a school assignment, sessions will do fine.

Comment: @bear: expecting your to-do list be there the next time, or from another browser/device is definitely **not** overengineering.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath can you list me the specifications of this system?

Comment: @Ruben Wouters $_SESSION['todoList'] will become the array.

Comment: @RubenWouters what the code now does (I've just updated it), is start the session (or reuse it). It then checks to see if a variable named `todoList` exists in the session, if it does use it, else, initialise it as an array. Of course, it could be improved. It then adds the item to the top of the array with `array_unshift`.

Comment: @RubenWouters read about `inline if` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-do-i-use-shorthand-if-else

Answer (score 0):

U could use a simple text file to store (append!) the new data at the end of the file if u can not use a database to store the existing tasks.

U also can easily read the content of the text file to display the existing data, for example each row == one task

save data

```
$fh = fopen('tasks.txt', 'a');
fwrite($task, $fh);
fclose($fh);
```

display data

```
$fh = fopen('tasks.txt', 'r');
$content = fread($fh, filesize('tasks.txt'));
fclose($fh);
```

Just as an idea. Make sure each task is in one row so u can easily go over the $content with for loop