# How to retrieve data in mysql table column?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, data-retrieval

In Mysql Table, I've a table name: **mental_illness** that there's two enum row inside as :

**N** and **P**

It means  Negative and Positive

and here's my PHP code to retrieve data from that table:

```
  if ($history->getMentalIllness())
  {
    echo HTML::section(3, _("Mental Illness : "));
    echo HTML::para(nl2br($history->getMentalIllness()));
  }
```

**Here's my question**:

How to use if else in that above PHP code like this:

If **Mental Illness** is **P**, then show **Positive** text
and If **Mental Illness** is **N** then show **Negative** text

> Because this code just show **P** and **N** instead of **Negative and
>   Positive text.**

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for something like [shorthand if else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-do-i-use-shorthand-if-else)?

Comment: Is there anyway to use if else in my php code that when it get N, it shows Negative and if it get P, it shows Positive?   As I mentioned, this code just show P and N not Negative and Positive text

Comment: Ok, what **specific part** of your code shows `N` or `F`? Is it `echo HTML::para(nl2br($history->getMentalIllness()));`?

Comment: Yes exactly thank you

Comment: I tested it this one, it doesn't work. is there other way ?

Comment: I mean elseif doesn't work  if (HTML::para(nl2br($history->getMentalIllness())) == "N"); {
    echo "Have a good day!";
} else
{
echo "Have a nice good day!";
}

Comment: I can get have a good day if its N  but If its P, it wont show other echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
if ($history->getMentalIllness())
{
  echo HTML::section(3, _("Mental Illness : "));
  if($history->getMentalIllness() == 'P'){
    $mental_illness = "Positive";
  }else{
    $mental_illness = "Negative";
  }
  echo HTML::para(nl2br($mental_illness));
}
```

One more thing... Why would you need nl2br in this case... There are no newlines in these two strings...

Comment: Thank you so much, Its working like charm. for nl2br i'm using for all codes in view page, It shouldn't be any problem for this. anyhow thanks for your advice. Merci :)