# PHP - If variable is not set, get post variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, post, isset

I am trying to pass through a variable to a new name if it is set, or get a POST variable if the first variable is not set.

This is my code but it is not working:

```
if (isset($randombg)) {
    $background = $randombg;    
} else {  
   $background = $_POST['bg']) 
};
```

What is wrong with it, or how can I fix this?

Comment: Please, could you substitute `is not working` with what really happens? See you some messages or typos?

Comment: Did you check my solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typos in your code. There is a `)` in `$background = $_POST['bg'])`
and a semicolon

you this should work:

```
$defaultbg = '#FFFFFF';

if (isset($randombg)) {
    $background = $randombg;    
} elseif( isset( $_POST['bg'] ) ) {  
   $background = $_POST['bg'];
   }else{
       $background = $defaultbg;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Feature] PHP 7.0.x +**

If you are using PHP 7.0.x+ you can use following syntax:

```
$background = $randombg ?? $_POST['bg'];
```

In this case `$background` will get value from first variable which is set and is not null.

You can do even something like this:

```
$background = $randombg ?? $_POST['bg'] ?? 'No background given'; 
// if $randombg and $_POST['bg'] will be not set or null $background will become 'No background given'
```

More about that feature you can read in [PHP RFC: Null Coalesce Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) and [PHP: New Features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

**About your code**

You have syntax in your code. More informations below:

```
if (isset($randombg)) {
    $background = $randombg;    
} else {  
   $background = $_POST['bg']) // you have syntax here, delete )
}
```

You can also use short syntax:

```
$background = (isset($randombg)) ? $randombg : $_POST['bg'];
```

And it works as follows:

```
$background = (condition) ? 'when true' : 'when false';
```

More about it you can read [here (Shorthand if/else)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-do-i-use-shorthand-if-else)

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the shorthand for 7.x. I was trying to avoid using `isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

Mauybe $randombg is null or empty (that does not exactly means that is not set).

Try this:

```
if ($randombg) {
    $background = $randombg;    
} else {  
    $background = $_POST['bg'];
}
```

Or a shorten syntax:

```
$background = null == $randombg
    ? $_POST['bg']
    : $randombg;
```

Comment: Please, don't do the second one. It's just too huge of a huge source of "why doesn't this code work"

Comment: Why not this sytax? It is way much better to read and much shorter if you write it in one line.

Comment: Sometimes code does not work because developers cant read the error.