# How to use isset condition for mysql query output

Tags: php, mysql

I get some data from MySQL, and I print the data as `echo $row['ref'];`.

Sometimes `echo $row['ref'];` returns empty result. I want to compose a condition like `echo isset($row['ref']) ? $row['ref']:'Unknown';` which will show `Unknown` word if `echo $row['ref'];` returns empty result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what's wrong with the isset?: code you mentioned?

Comment: But it does not display unknown word

Comment: use `empty` instead of `isset` the php function `empty` will check if the variable exist and is not empty

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps 'ref' is present as an array key but has null as value.

`<?php
$row = array('ref' => null);
echo (!empty($row['ref'])) ? $row['ref'] : 'UnKnown';
?>`

Comment: `??` is only for non-null. It does not do what `empty()` does.

Comment: the `empty` function alone is enough

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in your scenario which

```
isset($row['ref']) ? $row['ref']:'UnKnown';
```

you stated that you receive an empty value even you use isset which mean `$row['ref']` exist but it is empty

use `empty` instead of `isset` the php function `empty` will check if the variable exist and is not empty

This will prevent you from having an empty value for your variable `$ref`

```
$ref= (!empty($row["ref"])) ?$row["ref"]: "UnKnown";
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/699986)

Answer (score 0):

If `isset` doesn't work, it might be that mysqli returns the result as an empty string.

You may want to use the `?:` operator for quick if-false fallback:

```
echo $row["ref"] ?: "UnKnown";
```

See: [How do I use shorthand if / else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-do-i-use-shorthand-if-else)

Answer (score 0):

Try ternary operator like this......

```
$ref= $row["ref"] ?$row["ref"]: "UnKnown";
echo $ref;
```