# some laravel shortcode like a ? and : . please describe

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on laravel project. I have this code.

please explain

what is `?`  and `:`

```
if($request->pre_delivered){
    $grain_sale->undelivered_bushels = ($request->bushels_sold >= $request->pre_delivered ? $request->bushels_sold - $request->pre_delivered : NULl);
    dd($grain_sale->undelivered_bushels);
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's shorthand conditional code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-do-i-use-shorthand-if-else

Comment: This is a ternary operator, available in many languages. Just google it to understand how it works.

Comment: lol.it's ternary operator.. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @Dharmendrasingh Please do not make fun of newbies. Every one of us once was. We want StackOverflow to be a welcoming community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

if condition met then statement before `:` will execute otherwise after`:` will execute.

A very easy example to understand:- https://eval.in/771934

Answer (score 0):

There are already many posts about the *ternary operator* `?:`, but in short:

```
$var = condition ? <if true> : <if false>;
```

is a shorthand for:

```
if(condition){
    $var = <if true>;
}else{
    $var = <if false>;
}
```

Have a look at [the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for more details on the PHP implementation. Here is an extract:

> The expression `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)` evaluates to `expr2` if `expr1` evaluates to TRUE, and `expr3` if `expr1` evaluates to FALSE.
>   Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to TRUE, and `expr3` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). If the part before the `?` is true, the part right after `?` and before `:` is executed. If the part before `?` is false, the part after `:` is executed.

Answer (score -1):

ternary operator isn't a laravel thing it's a php operator and it's available in many languages too. have a look on [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) that describes the difference between `ternary` and `if`