# Use only function parameter if variable has a value

Tags: php, function, if-statement, parameters

I'm developing a small system to add records which be can opened later. On the page *view.php* it shows all records of all different country. I just extend this to only show one selected countries.

I call this function with the following argument:
`$toxRecords->getStatsCountry();`

If I want to show only one country, I just simple add the county code as parameter. Example:
`$toxRecords->getStatsCountry('NL');`

Because I use one page to show all countries but also one specific country it needs to check if there is an variable.
I check my *POST* with the following argument: `toxInput::get('country');`
This just simple return: `$_POST['country']`.

Now I just want that it will only use the function parameter if value *country* exists. This can be very simple, see below:

```
if($country = toxInput::get('country')) {
    $toxList = $toxRecords->getRecords($country);
} else {
    $toxList = $toxRecords->getRecords();
}
```

But I was wondering if it possible to shorten this to one single lane?
Example what I tried and will explain what I want:

```
$toxRecords->getRecords(if($country = toxInput::get('country')){ echo $country; });
```

Comment: I would expect to see this logic in the `getRecords` method rather than the controller, but maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this statement returns only one value through the condition:

```
condition ? value if condition is true : value if condition is false
```

for example:

```
$toxRecords->getRecords($country == toxInput::get('country') ? $country : "");
```

Comment: It returns a error: `Undefined variable: country`.
Trying to debug now..

Comment: It's because `$country` is not defined in your code scope @ChrisToxz

Comment: It works with this: `$toxRecords->getRecords(toxInput::get('country') ? toxInput::get('country') : "");`

Any solution to use a variable? Not necessary but just wondering.

Comment: But the code is trying to set variable in here `$country == toxInput::get('country')` . Why it is not setting this variable?

Comment: for condition you entered as `toxInput::get('country')` checks if it exists or not!

Comment: if you mean you want to check if `$country` equalation with `toxInput::get('country')` has done or not, it's not necessary to check it, because it'll done automatically  `$toxRecords->getRecords($country = toxInput::get('country'));`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
($val1 == $val2)? Echo "true" : Echo "False";
```

For more info check this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1506621/7116840