# "if" working but in "array" it not working

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple "if" code what works. In "array" it works but gets error "Undefined offset:". What is wrong?

code what works:

```
if (file_exists(glob($root . '/*/E0622.pdf')[0])) { 
    echo str_replace($root . '/', '', glob($root . '/*/E0622.pdf')[0]) ; 
} else {    
    echo 'x.pdf - no-no-no!' ;}
```

but in array gets " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in ":

```
'E0622' => 'E0622' . if (file_exists(glob($root . '/*/E0622.pdf')[0])) { 
    echo str_replace($root . '/', '', glob($root . '/*/E0622.pdf')[0])   
} else {    
    echo 'x.pdf - no-no-no!' } ,
```

What will be wrong?
Tnx!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve??

Comment: You're trying to add a string to 'E0622' but instead there follows an if, of course this doesn't work...

Comment: are you trying to create an array with a condition statement inside it?

Comment: `'E0622' => 'E0622' . (file_exists(glob($root . '/*/E0622.pdf')[0]) ?
str_replace($root . '/', '', glob($root . '/*/E0622.pdf')[0] :'x.pdf - no-no-no!'` ?

Answer (score 4):

The `if` statement itself cannot be used the way you are trying to do.

However, a [short-hand if-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-do-i-use-shorthand-if-else) statement exists. It is introduced for cases like yours.

It looks like this: `conditional-expression ? value-when-true : value-when-false`. This is an expression, so you can insert it everywhere you would insert any other expression.

```
$var = 7;
echo ($var == 7 ? "Var is seven" : "Var is not seven");
// Those parentheses are optional, but I added them for clarity.
```

It echoes "Var is seven".

This works:

```
'E0622' => 'E0622' . (file_exists(glob($root . '/*/E0622.pdf')[0]) ? str_replace($root . '/', '', glob($root . '/*/E0622.pdf')[0]) : 'x.pdf - no-no-no!'),
```

---

*PS: While you can nest as many short-hand if-else statements as you want, things may start to get really messy:*

```
$a = 1 == 1 ? 2 == 2 ? 3 == 4 ? 9 : 8 == 8 ? 1 : 2 : 7 : 6;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `if` construct in PHP is not an expression, and cannot be used in concatenation.

You need to change your structure to setting a variable to the thing you want to concatenate *first* and then adding that variable to the string.