# PHP Pulling content from a DIV using switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

I've set up a section on my site, to switch out content, based on the DIV ID called, but the initial "value" results in an error, if the variable isn't in the url.

the error i get:`Undefined index: item`

item is my variable.

My PHP is this:

```
<?php
    $url = 'file.php';
    $content = file_get_contents( $url );


    $item = $_GET[ 'item' ];
    switch ( $item ) {
        case "content1":
            $start = explode( '<div id="content1">', $content );
            $end = explode( "</div>", $start[ 1 ] );
            echo $end[ 0 ];
            break;

        case "content2":
            $start = explode( '<div id="content2">', $content );
            $end = explode( "</div>", $start[ 1 ] );
            echo $end[ 0 ];
            break;

        case "content3":
            $start = explode( '<div id="content3">', $content );
            $end = explode( "</div>", $start[ 1 ] );
            echo $end[ 0 ];
            break;

        default:
            $start = explode( '<div id="content1">', $content );
            $end = explode( "</div>", $start[ 1 ] );
            echo $end[ 0 ];
    }?>
```

So the code works fine if I append `?item=content1` at the end of my url, however, on initial visit (without the `?item=` at the end) i get the above error ( `Undefined index: item`)

What can I do so that if someone visits say index.php I won't get the error, and throw up the default called content?

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['item']))`

Comment: thanks, but i'm not sure what you are stating here.

Comment: That's how you test if they provided the parameter. The code that uses the parameter should be in that `if` statement.

Comment: Otherwise you just display the default contents.

Comment: Im not sure where in the code I'm supposed to include that or what I'm supposed to do with it.

Comment: Come on, this is trivial programming. You put it around all the code that depends on the variable.

Comment: @Keoki Have you learned about [if statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)? Use `isset($_GET['item'])` as the condition of the if statement and inside that if statement, put `$item = $_GET[ 'item' ];`

Comment: Chris, I did that and the content disappeared (nothing shows up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`if` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) to check if the variable is set. If not, set `$item` to a default value.

```
if (isset($_GET['item'])) {
    $item = $_GET['item'];
} else {
    $item = 'content1';
}
```

Also, there doesn't seem to be a need for the `switch/case` statement, since every case is identical except for what you're using as the `explode` delimiter.

```
$delimiter = '<div id="' . $item . '">';
$start = explode($delimiter, $content);
$end = explode("</div>", $start[ 1 ] );
echo $end[0];
```

It would probably be better to use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` instead of string matching to parse your content.

You could also use the [shorthand if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/) for this if you want to get really fancy.

Comment: chris, thanks, but your if (isset) also produces the same error.

Comment: It shouldn't. You replaced the assignment with this `if` statement, right?