# Change color based on value of a variable

Tags: php, sql

I'm having trouble changing the color of a value if it is a certain word, I'm using PDO to get data from a database, will be pasting the code down below.

What I want is .. if the variable " estado " is " Em analise " then the color should be red..

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM orcamento");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "<div class='panel-body'>";
    echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<center>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "
    <th>#&nbsp;</th>    
    <th>Estado</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo"</thead>";
    echo "<br>";
    while ($rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "
        <td>$rs->CodOrc &nbsp; </td> 
        <td>$rs->estado &nbsp; </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: The color of what? The whole row? The cell? The background color? The text color?

Comment: the cell, wich is " estado " .. if estado returns " Em analise " then it should be the color red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't echo so much HTML with PHP, simply switch between the 2 languages. I did that for you in the code below, it will allow HTML to properly highlight its own syntax so you can sniff out bugs easier. It's never a good idea to echo all of your HTML with PHP, you should only do that when necessary and if you do have to do that you should use [Heredocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or similar.

Next, what you're trying to do is actually pretty easy. Simply use a [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to check if `$rs->estado` is equal to the value you want, and supply a class or style to the cell.

```
<?
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM orcamento");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    ?>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <div class='table-responsive'>

        <style>
            .red {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>

        <table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>
            <thead>
                <center>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#&nbsp;</th>    
                        <th>Estado</th>";
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                 while ($rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>{$rs->CodOrc} &nbsp; </td>";
                        echo "<td class='".($rs->estado == 'Em analise' ? "red" : "")."'>{$rs->estado} &nbsp; </td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>   
        </table>
<?php
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

The main part of this solution is the ternary, `".($rs->estado == 'Em analise' ? 'red' : '')."` which basically tells PHP that if `$rs->estado` is equal to `Em analise`, it should echo the word `red`, and if it does not it echo's an empty string .

Note: The style tag in my answer should probably actually be added to a `.css` file.

Comment: Thank you!! not only fixed my problem it organized my code! Have a great day dude thank you so much

Comment: @PedroMiguel Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class in your CSS:

```css
.red { color: #f00; }
```

And add a class attribute of your `<td>` tag:

```php
$match = $rs->estado == 'Em analise' ;
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$rs->CodOrc &nbsp; </td> 
      <td".($match?' class="red"':'').">$rs->estado &nbsp; </td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

As you're asking a very basic question, I'll give you the someone complex answer with some extra explanation:

```
echo "<td class='".($rs->estado=='Em analise'?'highlight':'')."'>".$rs->estado." &nbsp; </td>";
```

I did a few things here:

- [I escaped the variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). You can see in the color highlighting this reads easier. This is not really always needed, but IMO a good practice. Using the color highligher might give you a better indication where a possible bug is when you get more used to it.
- I've added [a short else if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-do-i-use-the-ternary-operator-in-php-as-a-shorthand-for-if-else) (`statement ? ifTrue : ifFalse`). It is a short method which allowed a simple inline check instead of a little bigger `if()else{}`. You can do the longer one if you prefer, but you might want to toy arround with this a bit.
- Instead of adding a style, I've added a highlight class. Styling belongs in a stylesheet, not in code (code is for logic). You can now reuse the stlye in another table or element. Or also add pink font,some padding and/or other funky *style* stuff without having to change your *logic*.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! it helped me a lot! Have a great day

Comment: If you like a post on StackOverflow, it recommended to upvote that post, so that others can see that it helped someone out :) That way, good answers get more visible