# Fill html table with php rand() numbers

Tags: php, random

I need to fill a 10x10 html table using php code with a random number from 1-10 rand(1,10), then depending on the result paint the cell red if <5 or green if >5. i manually created 10 rows with 10 td each and inside I put echo(rand(1,10)) for each one of them but my syntax is wrong and it looks gross

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: i manually created 10 <tr> with 10 <td> each and inside I put echo(rand(1,10)) for each one of them but my syntax is wrong and it looks gross, I am a php beginner so...

Comment: Welcome to the community Winston. This is an inappropriate question to ask on StackOverflow; members of the community are not here to write your code for you. Please update this question with a description of what you have already tried and an explanation how your chosen solution has not been successful.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I updated my question to fully represent my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) : ?>
            <tr>
                <?php for ($k = 0; $k < 10; $k++) : ?>
                    <?php $num = rand(1, 10); ?>
                    <td style="color: <?= $num < 5 ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>"><?= $num; ?></td>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this almost did the job, I need the table cell be painted not the number itself, also can you do this using if...else statements instead of the 'red' : 'green' options?

Comment: I replaced color with background and it worked, now I only need it be done with if...else statements depending on the inside numbers

Comment: My answer uses `if/else` statements based on the inside numbers.  It's just using a ternary `if` instead of the standard `if` format.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-do-i-use-the-ternary-operator-in-php-as-a-shorthand-for-if-else

Comment: can you write only the middle line using classic if...else?

Comment: The equivalent of 
    `<?= $num < 5 ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>`
with a classic `if/else` would be
    `<?php if ($num < 5) echo 'red'; else echo 'green'; ?>`

I suggest you read this section of the php docs to get a better understanding:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

And here is a great article explaining the benefits of ternary operators:
https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators