# Array values not passing on a function

Tags: php

The code explains to find the max and min number, However, I passed an array on the function
But the output doesn't seem to appear on the browser, It's blank. I assume the Logic is 100% fine. Also, I would like someone to teach me the syntax of how to pass arrays in a function. Because I have trouble passing array values in PHP. A solution would be great

```
<?php
$test=array(9,7,3,13,1); // sample array
function maximum($array) // function to find maximum value in an array
{ 


 $slot=$array[0]; // fixed the first value of the array
 $length=count($array); // length of the array
 for($i=1; $i<$length; $i++)
 {
       $slot = ($slot<$array[$i]) ? $array[$i] : " "; // comparing the fixed value with other values
 }
 
 echo $slot."<br>"; // final max value
 
}

function minimum($array)  // function to find minimum value in an array
{
  
 
 $slot=$array[0]; // fixed the first value of the array
 $length=count($array);  // length of the array
 for($i=1; $i<$length; $i++)
 {
       
     $slot= ($slot>$array[$i]) ? $array[$i] : " "; // comparing the fixed value with other values
 }
 
 echo $slot; // final max value
 
}
echo maximum($test); //passing the $test array to find the max
echo minimum($test); //passing the $test array to find the min

?>
```

Comment: `I assume the Logic is 100% fine` No, your logic is wrong, it should be `$slot = ($slot<$array[$i]) ? $array[$i] : $slot;` in the maximum function. Similar issue with the minimum

Comment: What @catcon said. Plus you should also return `$slot` from the functions.

Comment: I am not involving anything, on the else part. So is that correct if I put $slot?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an exercise in writing code and you don't want to use `min()` and `max()`, there are two problems with the code you have written.

The first is that the functions don't actually return anything, they just `echo` the result.

The second is that when you compare the current number with the new element in the array, you swap it if it is a better match, but set it to `" "` if it isn't...

```
$slot= ($slot>$array[$i]) ? $array[$i] : " ";
```

so the end value of `$slot` is usually a single space.  This should be

```
$slot = ($slot<$array[$i]) ? $array[$i] : $slot;
```

So your function (without any major logic changes) should be something like...

```
function maximum($array) // function to find maximum value in an array
{
    $slot=$array[0]; // fixed the first value of the array
    $length=count($array); // length of the array
    for($i=1; $i<$length; $i++)
    {
        $slot = ($slot<$array[$i]) ? $array[$i] : $slot; // comparing the fixed value with other values
    }
    
    return $slot; // final max value
}
```

Comment: can you explain me what happens to the value if i apply this?

$slot = ($slot<$array[$i]) ? $array[$i] : $slot;

because if the condtion is true it will be $slot = $array[$i]; but why put $slot on the else part. If i convert it into if statements.
if($slot<$array[$i])
{
      $slot =  $array[$i]
}
else
{
    $slot = $slot;
}

Comment: The main thing about a ternary expression (`?:`) is that the end result will be one of the two values.  So in this case the else part is run and will set the `$slot` value to `" "`.  When you use an `if` you can say that you only want to do something if the value is true, if there is no `else` then nothing happens.

Comment: what if I want to place on single value on the ternary operator when the condition is true? How will the syntax look like? Can you please share?

Comment: With a ternary - you can't do that.  There is a short version, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52837891/1213708, but that only works if the value isn't false (it also sets the first value to be the result of the condition itself).

Comment: Thanx @Nigel Ren. Your solution was very helpful :). I am a beginner so I have lots of doubt man.  I hope i did not ask you any stupid questions :)

Answer (score 1):

To call a function just use below format

```
     maximum($test); 
     minimum($test);
```

No need to put echo before the function

Please change the logic to

$slot= ($slot>$array[$i]) ? $array[$i] : $slot;