# How to convert an if condition to ternary operator in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, conditional-operator, ternary

I am very new to the laravel, I am writing a normal if condition I want to convert that if condition to ternary operator ,please help me to convert it

```
$posts=DB::table('posts')->where('name',$id)->exists();
if($posts == false)
return $user->hasRole() ||$user->hasRights();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace "if" statement with a ternary operator ( ? : )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-to-replace-if-statement-with-a-ternary-operator)

Comment: Laravel is a PHP framework, so a Ternary is as documented: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary, basically `$boolean ? $ifTrue : $ifFalse`. That being said, `if(!$posts){ ... } else { ... }` is perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Laravel but I think it's a PHP framework, so, as documented [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
return $posts == false ? $user->hasRole() ||$user->hasRights() : return_val_if_false
```

You said you don't want to specify a return value if false. In that case you can simply do:

```
return $posts == false && ($user->hasRole() ||$user->hasRights());
```

This doesn't use ternary operators though, there is no way to do what you specifically want I think.

Comment: There is no false statement in my case is it work without false statement

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: `return null;` on `false` condition is perfectly valid in PHP  aka `return !$posts ? ... : null;`

Comment: @Konrad, what is the meaning of this line why you use && operator

Comment: It's the "and" operator: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is the same as Javascript with

`[condition] ? [if true] : [if false]`

if you want to refer to this is not Laravel, because Laravel is just a framework, you need to look for PHP because PHP is the language.