# PHP: is there a good syntax to initialize an array element depending on whether it is undefined or not, without using if?

Tags: php, syntax, null-coalescing-operator

The double question mark syntax in PHP

```
$foo = $bar ?? null;
```

will return null if $bar is undefined. This syntax is extremely useful to simplify code and avoid massive if statements.

Now I have the following situation

```
if (!isset($bar2)) {
    $fooArr = [$bar1];
} else {
    $fooArr = [$bar1, $bar2];
}
```

It seems so likely that there exists a one-line simplification for the statement but I just couldn't come up with it.

The closest I come up with is the following, but it will create an array with size 2 where the second element is null, which is not what I want.

```
$fooArr = [$bar1, $bar2 ?? null];
```

Is there a way to simplify the aforementioned nested if without using if statement?

Edit : the `? :` syntax works for the above case but I will still have to write down `$bar1` twice in that situation, which is not much neater than the if statement and can grow really big when the array consists of 5 elements.

Comment: ```$bar1 && $a = 3;``` I think that will do it to define variable. But in your case I think it's  ```$fooArr = $bar1 ? [$bar1, $bar2] : [$bar1 ]```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace "if" statement with a ternary operator ( ? : )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-to-replace-if-statement-with-a-ternary-operator)

Comment: @gre_gor That works, but I will need to write $bar1 twice like `$bar2 ? [$bar1, $bar2] : [$bar1]`. This can becomes really long when the array consists of say 5 elements and the last element is what I want to branch on. Wondering if there is a way without the need to write down every array element twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method only returns the non-empty values from an array by default.

This code shows the various outcomes:

```
$bar1=1;
$fooArr = [$bar1, $bar2 ?? null];
print_r($fooArr);

$bar2=2;
$fooArr = [$bar1, $bar2 ?? null];
print_r($fooArr);

unset($bar1,$bar2);

$bar1=1;
$fooArr = array_filter([$bar1, $bar2 ?? null]);
print_r($fooArr);

$bar2=2;
$fooArr = array_filter([$bar1, $bar2 ?? null]);
print_r($fooArr);
```

[Teh playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/51EwFcXfo1A4DNnC)